# how to detect an order placed with shopware 6.5 (event subscribers) and also get its present state

Tags: php, symfony, events, shopware6, subscriber

Hello I am trying to detect when a new order comes into my store using shopware 6.5

this is what I am doing :

`OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'OnOrderReceived',`

`public function OnOrderReceived(EntityWrittenEvent $event) { if ($event->getEntityName() === 'order') {`

```
        $writtenEntities = $event->getWriteResults();


        foreach ($writtenEntities as $writeResult) {
            // Get the entity data from the write result
            $entityData = $writeResult->getPayload();

            // Get the order ID from the entity data
            $orderId = $entityData['id'];
            $orderNumber = $entityData['orderNumber'];

            // $this->logger->info('Orders is created, the order id is : ' . $orderId . ' and order number : ' . $orderNumber);

        }


    }

}`
```

With this I am able to get the order Id and number, but I can't seem to capture the present state of the order e.g "open". please how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT` is a pretty low level technical event, so it is quite hard to get the infos out there that you need.

You should better listen to the `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Event\CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent` as that event gives you easy access to the info you need:

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
   return [
       CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'onOrderPlaced',
   ];
}

public function onOrderPlaced(CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent $event): void
{
    $orderId = $event->getOrderId();
    $state = $event->getOrder()->getStateMachineState()->getName();
}
```

Comment: just a bit confused, this is shopware 6.5 before calling my methods and according to the documentation I need to return  return [
            ProductEvents::PRODUCT_SEARCH_RESULT_LOADED_EVENT => 'onProductSearched',
            OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'OnOrderReceived',
        ];   and so in the context of "CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent". what do I point to?

Comment: That's nothing shopware specific, that's the way symfony event subscribers work, so i suggest to checkout the official docs for that, do actually understand what's going on there: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

I've updated the answer with the event subscriber config.

Comment: thank you so much, that gave me a better understanding. is there any community I can follow up for symfony and shopware hints like this. Thanks

Comment: and yes it works, I just injected the state machine class and i got the state

Comment: The symfony docs are a pretty good start, as we (shopware) tries to follow the symfony defaults as much as possible. For shopware there is a open community slack workspace you may want to join: shopwarecommunity.slack.com

For symfony there probably is something similiar

Comment: hello @j_elfering there docent seem to be a way to get payment details, discount details about this order for example

Comment: You should then inject the needed repositories into your subscriber and fetch the details you need manually from the db using the repositories and the IDs of the provided data.

Comment: can the "   CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'OnOrderReceived'," be triggered after a customer pays online using a payment processor